# How does "qwik-react" convert a React component to a Qwik component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chakra-ui, qwik

How does "qwik-react" convert a React component to a Qwik component? Does it simply make it compatible with Qwik or does it transform it into a true Qwik component? Is there any advantage for developers to build Qwik components and libraries?

For example, if I want to use Chakra UI as my UI kit, according to the Qwik website documentation, should I create a file named "chakra-ui-qwik" and export each component I want to use in the following manner:

```js
import { qwikify$ } from '@builder.io/qwik-react';
import { Box, Container, Divider, Link, Text } from "@chakra-ui/react";

export const QBox = qwikify$(Box);
export const QContainer = qwikify$(Container);
export const QDivider = qwikify$(Divider);
export const QLink = qwikify$(Link);
export const QText = qwikify$(Text);
```

So there is no need for developers to develop @chakra-ui/qwik library and @chakra-ui/react is enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find [UI libraries](https://qwik.builder.io/community/projects/#components-libraries) that allow you to use the Qwik optimizations.
In fact, using react inside Qwik is possible, but losing some benefits that the framework offers you.

In the Qwik documentation, [qwikify section](https://qwik.builder.io/docs/integrations/react/#qwikify) you can find several information.

*Extract from the documentation:*

Using React components in Qwik is a great way to migrate your application to Qwik, but it's not a silver bullet, you will need to rewrite your components to take advantage of Qwik's features.

> Don't abuse qwikify$() to build your application, as overusing will cause performance gains to be lost.